# MYSQL primary key strategy for microservices architecture

Tags: mysql

We are currently using auto-generated primary keys and we would like to switch to an approach which is more suitable for microservices applications: either we are going to use business defined primary key (a tax code for persons) or global unique identifiers.

In the past we had performance issues when using business-defined primary keys instead of autoincrement, is it still the case? Does MySQL support strong GUID so that we could have unique uuid even across databases?
Eventually, is there a better approach we are not considering?

Comment: My SQL support the generation of  UUIDs according to RFC 4122 which is pretty unique. MySQL Documentation for [UUID (function)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid)

Answer (score 1):

Corrected:

with MySQL You can store GUID/UUID data as char/varchar in case of UUID() and UNSIGNED INTEGER in case of UUID_SHORT()

My personal vision - UUID_SHORT not working case, it is unsigned INT same as Auto-Increment and You can read restrictions in function description.

UUID() will return result as utf8 string - "eabd691c-b552-11e6-942e-ee8ae5dda6a8"

Business logic for primary key - work well, You always mange this process and do not need spend time for call function.

**add after question in comment:**

performance not depend from business logic or auto increment, it depend mostly from 2 parameters:

- size of column
- function duration time

**INT (BIGINT)** always will be smaller than CHAR(36) - as result less memory usage, more data in memory for index recreate operations (such as massive insert)

**Increment** will be faster any other form of random generator in 99% of cases

So in case of TAXNUMBER as primary key:

- advantage - no any function for generate this type of key
- disadvantage - most of them will take more memory than INT (BIGINT)

**Add some visual examples:**
make a proper test it very hard, but this is small example:
was created 3 tables, with only 1 column ID - primary key

- UNSIGNED INT AUTOINCREMENT
- BINARY(16)
- VARCHAR(36)

was created stored procedure which insert 11M of records in each table, time results, very close:

- 11m41s - INT
- 12m40s - UUID() -> binary(16)
- 12m40s - UUID() -> varchar(36)

with time difference will need adjust server settings
but if we check size on disk (tables include only 1 column, PK)

```
-rw-r-----  1 _mysql  _mysql   1.1G 29 Nov 01:00 t__binary.ibd
-rw-r-----  1 _mysql  _mysql   268M 29 Nov 01:01 t__uint.ibd
-rw-r-----  1 _mysql  _mysql   1.6G 29 Nov 01:00 t__varchar.ibd
```

we can see the difference, and as bigger will be data, as much more will be difference

Comment: I remember having performance issues when using non auto-increment values on massive inserts, is this still the case?

Comment: CHAR(36) still use more memory than INT or BIGINT, and +1 still faster than random generator

Comment: No native support? What about [`UUID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid)?

Comment: it still will be - utf8 string "b07ad226-b552-11e6-942e-ee8ae5dda6a8", may be I not correct explain, but I mean - it no any compressed form of this

Comment: The best is to use `BINARY(16)`, not CHAR. 16 bytes over 36 is a lot of improvement.

Comment: it will be 1 more transformation

Comment: Yes, but the saving in table and index space will be huge.

Comment: one moment - I always prefer to check - it finish soon (2 processes with 1M inserts)

Comment: Test was not correct - data too small and server too fast (4core,4Ghz+RAM), with simple 1 column tables and 1M inserts - difference less than 1 sec, 114-115-114sec for all 3 cases (115 it case of BINARY).  Size as expected - INT 31Mb, BINARY - 44Mb, VARCHAR - 68Mb

Comment: Performance suffers significantly when `SELECTing` by UUID from a table too big to fit in the buffer_pool.  Try your 1GB tests with a buffer_pool of only 100M.

Comment: @RickJames - as I wrote, it very hard to make proper test, need choose proper hardware. I repeat tests with 10M (included in answer). It simple - when You have 40G of RAM, even if make 100Mb for InnoDB, MacOS take all other for file level cache (now it 24G) ... and hard to see difference, will need re-do on machine restricted with resources, I and without test agree - it will be better, just was idea show this

Answer (score 0):

*(This answer does not fully answer your question; it is intended to enlighten you about the issues of GUID/UUID performance issues, plus some mitigation.)*

> In the past we had performance issues when using business-defined
>   primary keys instead of autoincrement, is it still the case?

Yes.  But it can be mitigated *some*.  When you have a huge database (more data than can be cached in RAM), UUIDs start to perform poorly, eventually (as the data grows) degenerating to one disk I/O per one reference to a UUID-based record.  For huge databases, this is untenable.  The mitigation is to use *only* Type-1 UUIDs (which is what MySQL's `UUID()` is), *and* rearrange the bits so that the date&time is at the beginning.  This is beneficial *if* your data references are biased to "recent" rows, thereby making the caching more efficient.  Changing from 36 *characters* into 16 *bytes* also helps with performance.

I discuss this more in [*my blog*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/guiduuid-performance/) .  In [*MySQL 8.0*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-to-bin), Oracle picked up the ball and implemented `UUID_TO_BIN()` and related functions to both rearrange the bits and pack into `VARBINARY(16)`.

> Does MySQL support strong GUID so that we could have unique uuid even
>   across databases?

You can obviously create your own GUID/UUID and use it as a globally-unique key for whatever you want.  MySQL has its builtin `UUID()` function, which is "Type-1".  I don't know whether you consider that to be "strong"; it seems fine.

> Eventually, is there a better approach we are not considering?

That question is too broad.